# Dart - Need to hit submit button twice in order to save data in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Context: I am building out a form to store some simple user information for my senior project. There are 3 fields and a submit button. The user information is stored in firestore in the user document.

Problem: When I hit submit, the fields in the user document that are being updated are set to null. Then in order for the fields to be updated in the user document to be updated, the submit button needs to be hit a second time.

userSettingsPage.dart

```
void _submitForm() {
final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;

var userManager = new UserManager();
userManager.updateUser(updatedUser, mCurrentUser.uid);

if (!form.validate()) {
  showMessage('Form is not valid!  Please review and correct.');
} else {
  form.save(); //This invokes each onSaved event
 }
}

bool isValidUserCode(String input) {
RegExp regex = new RegExp('');
switch(input){
  case '123456789': {
    newUserRole = "professor";
    regex = new RegExp('123456789');
  }
  break;
  case '987654321': {
    newUserRole = "security";
    regex = new RegExp('987654321');
  }
  break;
  case '666': {
    newUserRole = "student";
    regex = new RegExp('666');
  }
  break;
  case '': {
     regex = new RegExp('');

  }
}
return regex.hasMatch(input);

}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Settings'),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: new Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidate: true,
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Name',
                labelText: 'Your Name'
              ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (val) => updatedUser.name = val
            ),
            new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '1234567',
                    labelText: 'ID number'
                ),
              inputFormatters: [new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7)],
                onSaved: (val) => updatedUser.ID = val
            ),
            new TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'User Role Code',
                    labelText: 'Enter code (for faculty and staff only)',
                ),
                validator: (value) => isValidUserCode(value) ? null : 'Not a valid code',
                onSaved: (value) => updatedUser.role = newUserRole,
            ),
            new Text("Bugs suck, please hit submit button twice in order to send data.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20.0, right: 40.0),
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: _submitForm,
                )
            ),
            new Text("Changes will take effect next time you close and reopen page.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ],
        )
    ),
  ),
);
```

userManager.dart

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final Firestore _firestoreDB = Firestore.instance;


Future<void> updateUser(User user, String uid) async {
  Map<String, dynamic> userData = Map();
  userData["name"] = user.name;
  userData["ID"] = user.ID;
  userData["role"] = user.role;
  Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(uid).setData(userData, merge: true);
}
```

Can't figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use controllers to get text from TextFormField as below, it will get text from TextFormField and assign it to updatedUser properties when the _submitForm() called:

```
void _submitForm() {
final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;

setState(() {
    updatedUser.name = controllerName.text;
    updatedUser.ID = controllerID.text;
    updatedUser.role = controllerRole.text;
});

var userManager = new UserManager();
userManager.updateUser(updatedUser, mCurrentUser.uid);

if (!form.validate()) {
  showMessage('Form is not valid!  Please review and correct.');
} else {
  form.save(); //This invokes each onSaved event
 }
}

final TextEditingController controllerName = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController controllerID = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController controllerRole = TextEditingController();


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Settings'),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: new Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidate: true,
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerName,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Name',
                labelText: 'Your Name'
              ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (val) => updatedUser.name = val
            ),
            new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerID,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '1234567',
                    labelText: 'ID number'
                ),
              inputFormatters: [new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(7)],
                onSaved: (val) => updatedUser.ID = val
            ),
            new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerRole,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'User Role Code',
                    labelText: 'Enter code (for faculty and staff only)',
                ),
                validator: (value) => isValidUserCode(value) ? null : 'Not a valid code',
                onSaved: (value) => updatedUser.role = newUserRole,
            ),
            new Text("Bugs suck, please hit submit button twice in order to send data.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, top: 20.0, right: 40.0),
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: _submitForm,
                )
            ),
            new Text("Changes will take effect next time you close and reopen page.", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ],
        )
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey this works great, only now my isValidUserCode function doesnt work and just gives Firestore the code the user entered instead of the role determined

Comment: I GOT IT, in your code i replaced controllerRole.text with newUserRole.